# Reuse a column made with a conditional aggregation in the next column

Tags: sql, sql-server

The conditional aggregation done on 'tapers' is the same as the one used in the case of the next column. Is there a way to take the value of the previous one without rewriting everything again?

```
select 
    idComedor      = IdComedor
    , total = SUM(case when NombreArea in ('APLICACIONES','ARANDANOS','PALTO')  then Cantidad else 0 end)
    , cajas = SUM(case when NombreArea in ('APLICACIONES','ARANDANOS','PALTO')  then Cantidad else 0 end)%12
    , tapers = SUM(case when NombreArea in ('APLICACIONES','ARANDANOS','PALTO')  then Cantidad else 0 end)/12
    , cajasNeto = CASE WHEN SUM(case when NombreArea in ('APLICACIONES','ARANDANOS','PALTO')  then Cantidad else 0 end)/12> 0 THEN 
SUM(case when NombreArea in ('APLICACIONES','ARANDANOS','PALTO')  then Cantidad else 0 end)%12 + 1 ELSE 
SUM(case when NombreArea in ('APLICACIONES','ARANDANOS','PALTO')  then Cantidad else 0 end)%12 END
    , tachos =  CEILING(SUM(case when NombreArea in ('APLICACIONES','ARANDANOS','PALTO')   then Cantidad else 0 end)*0.9/45)
from dbo.vSolDistrib
where idlocalidad = 2 and FechaPedido = '2022.05.26'
group by IdComedor
```

Comment: You could use a cte to do the conditional aggregation, then in your query you would just join to the cte and do specific calculation you want.

Comment: Sub-query (of which a CTE is one type).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery, something like this

```
select  t.IdComedor  
        ,total = t.calcsum
        ,cajas = t.calcsum % 12
        ,tapers = t.calcsum / 12
        ,cajasNeto = CASE WHEN t.calcsum / 12 > 0 THEN t.calcsum % 12 + 1 
                          ELSE t.calcsum % 12 
                     END
       ,tachos =  CEILING(t.calcsum * 0.9 / 45)
from  (select idComedor = IdComedor
              ,SUM(case when NombreArea in ('APLICACIONES','ARANDANOS','PALTO')  then Cantidad else 0 end) as calcsum
       from   dbo.vSolDistrib
       where  idlocalidad = 2 and FechaPedido = '2022.05.26'
       group by IdComedor
      ) t
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6afc5dbf5676f4e5e1bc2c53270453c) here, you can fill it with data to test if it works like you want